# getting com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out error

Tags: gradle, marklogic-10

ml-gradle version: 4.1.0
Gradle wrapper version: 6.7
MarkLogic version: 10.0.9.4
Java version: java1.8.0_202
Teamcity agent : window

we have set up a TeamCity agent with an http_proxy configuration that's used to deploy the code on the marklogic server. However, during deployment, I am facing the following errors:

Error 1:

```
[org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] HTTP GET http://host-server:8001/admin/v1/timestamp
 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Accept=[text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/json, application/*+xml, application/*+json, */*]
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {}->http://host-server:8001][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 224][route: {}->http://host-server:8001][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {}->http://host-server:8001
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to host-server/IP address:8001 
 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] 
 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :mlDeployApp
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-224: Shutdown connection
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
 [ERROR] [com.marklogic.mgmt.admin.AdminManager] Reached limit of 30, and MarkLogic has not restarted yet; check MarkLogic status
 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 224][route: {}->http://host-server:8001][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
 [INFO] [com.marklogic.mgmt.admin.AdminManager] Waiting for MarkLogic to restart, attempt: 31
```

Error 2 (at the end):

```
Execution failed for task ':mlDeployApp'. com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Could someone provide guidance on what might be causing this error?